# toastr Notification not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, notifications, toastr

I've included toaster.css, toaster.js and jquery like that:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/toaster.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="QtApp/Notifications/toaster.css" />
```

and i am sure that the paths are correct. But when I try to call toaster.pop(..) or toaster.error(..) the respective functions are called and executed but no popup is shown. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Please put your code . Other wise try using toastr.success() or toastr.error() instead of toaster.success() or toaster.error()

Comment: I have an error controller which uses the name toaster for the instance of toastr. So the name is not a problem

Comment: Please put your code plunker.

Answer (score 0):

The js file you are referencing looks like it has a typo

```
<script src="Scripts/toaster.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="Scripts/toastr.js"></script>
```

The same with your css.

When you go to the 'sources' tab in the browser dev tools are you able to navigate to the js and css files?